# What is the channel and server for Braintree's IRC?

Tags: irc, braintree

I started using Braintree's libraries last week and the first day I was happily able to use the links on their site to find the Braintree IRC channel/server and connected to it with XChat.

Yesterday I had a few questions I figured I'd ask and was going to hop on, so I jumped onto the Braintree website again but couldn't find the link. So I emailed their support and they told me to hop onto https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact and use the 'chat with sales' button.

That button just pops up a form to email or chat with them, I'm looking for the channel and which IRC server they're hosted on. Does anyone have that info?

Comment: I work at Braintree. We don't have an IRC channel; not sure where you got that idea. There is a web-based live chat service that will connect you with a sales rep when there is one available, or you can reach us on the phone or via email. For questions about our client libraries and integrating with Braintree, email is generally the best medium.

Comment: I think I saw that web portal the other day, then popped open the source of the page and grabbed the server url and used it in my IRC client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Braintree again and got this response.

> Thanks for getting back to us. Currently our chat room is only for our sales team. If you need any assistance you can email us at `support@braintreepayments.com` or give us a call at `877.434.2894` Monday – Friday 9am to 5pm central time. We will be happy to get back to you as soon as possible.

It's good to get an official response, but it's really strange because I was connected via my IRC client the other day to a server/channel listed from the website. Oh well maybe connected to an unofficial one or something and my memory is going.

Comment: Snap Engage, the service we use for chat, doesn't use IRC as its backend. You must have been looking at another, similar service that has an IRC channel.

Comment: I think I must have been looking at balanced payments, sorry about the confusion. but thanks for the response :)

Comment: Sure :) We're pretty easy to get in touch with, IRC channel or no. In addition to 1->1 communication, there is always here, GitHub, Twitter, Quora, etc., which aren't official support channels but which we generally try to keep up with.